# How should I start Checo-style training?

Tags: pull-ups, checo

I have been training for 9 months and am now able to do a human flag pole. I intend to go more into Checo-style training.

The exercises mostly require the pull up bar; the human flag pole is one representative example. There are several types of pull up that I am aware of (although I don't know the styles by name). One example is, after pulling up, pushing one's self upward into a deep position. Another example is hanging one's self from the pull up bar and slowly pushing the whole body parallel to the ground, while keeping the hands straight (holding the pull up bar).

Any advice on how to make progress with this style training?

Comment: What is gecko training?

Comment: For me i think it is the toughest training i have seen now. I do not know what other name the training have. If u got facebook u could go to this group called barstarzz and u can see the type of training they undergo.

Comment: You'll need to describe the program you are asking about.

Comment: Do you mean "Checo" (not gecko), the founder of the Barstarzz team? I just found the website: http://www.barstarzz.com/ But they don't outline a training program. They just show off what they can do. You also just list a few examples of what you'd like to do. Is there a more concrete training program involved or is that what you're asking us advise about?

Comment: I meant that checo. sorry wrong spelling. I am asking on advise how to start about training on it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do [Muscle-Ups](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJX1pxL-NMo).  This is best progession I've found though you will need gymnastics rings: [Muscle up Progression from CrossFit Estero](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hN7nX4_ycs)

Here's an excellent progression for the second exercise which is a [front lever](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysqkaCxv2bI).

Answer (score 0):

BarStarzz has a [DVD](http://www.barstarzz.com/store/) showing how to get started on what they do, starting from the absolute basics.